# PostgreSQL - Ignore missing column when adding row

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to ignore values with missing columns when using `INSERT INTO` in PostgreSQL?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO tblExample(col_Exist1, col_Exist2, col_NotExist) VALUES ('Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3)
```

I want to insert a new row containing values `Val1` and `Val2`, but ignore `Val3` since its column does not exist, so the result would be:

```
 # | col_Exist1 | col_Exist2
-----------------------------
 1 | Val1       | Val2
```

I see that there is a `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` construct, but this seems to apply to an entire row only - not a singular value.

For explanation, I realise this may be not best practice, but my application is using dynamically created queries based on properties from documents - the properties *can* vary, but there are lots of columns, so defining them explicitly is painful. Instead, I'm using a 'template' document to define them and, hopefully, I can just ignore properties from other documents that don't exist in the template document.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've figured out a workaround for now - I'm just querying the table to get the list of columns - if the column name exists, add the property to the new `INSERT INTO` query. The original question still stands.

Comment: Seems you have created a dynamic error generator. No, there is not a way for an `INSERT` to ignore extra data.

Answer (score 0):

What about moving document's data to json?
Form one table where you will have following fields:

```
Table: Documents

   id: uuid4
   name: varchar or text
   data: json type according https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/datatype-json.html
```

After this trick you can store any dynamical data you'd like